# Prevent redirection to mobile version for Google bot

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, googlebot

There is a site mysite.com and subdomain m.mysite.com. For redirection for mobile devices from mysite.com to m.mysite.com I use following code in htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# Check if this is the noredirect query string
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)m=0(&|$)
# Set a cookie, and skip the next rule
RewriteRule ^ - [CO=mredir:0:mysite.com]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:x-wap-profile} !^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Profile}       !^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "acs|alav|alca|amoi|audi|aste|avan|benq|bird|blac|blaz|brew|cell|cldc|cmd-" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "dang|doco|eric|hipt|inno|ipaq|java|jigs|kddi|keji|leno|lg-c|lg-d|lg-g|lge-" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT}  "maui|maxo|midp|mits|mmef|mobi|mot-|moto|mwbp|nec-|newt|noki|opwv" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "palm|pana|pant|pdxg|phil|play|pluc|port|prox|qtek|qwap|sage|sams|sany" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "sch-|sec-|send|seri|sgh-|shar|sie-|siem|smal|smar|sony|sph-|symb|t-mo" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "teli|tim-|tosh|tsm-|upg1|upsi|vk-v|voda|w3cs|wap-|wapa|wapi" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "wapp|wapr|webc|winw|winw|xda|xda-" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "up.browser|up.link|windowssce|iemobile|mini|mmp" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "symbian|midp|wap|phone|pocket|mobile|pda|psp" [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !macintosh [NC]

# Check if we're not already on the mobile site
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}          !^m\.
# Can not read and write cookie in same request, must duplicate condition
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)m=0(&|$) 

# Check to make sure we haven't set the cookie before
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE}        !^.*mredir=0.*$ [NC]

# Now redirect to the mobile site
RewriteRule ^ http://m.mysite.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
</IfModule>
```

Now the problem is that images hosted at mysite.com but not at m.mysite.com, and inserted in email message, are not loaded in Gmail. Probably because Google bot is being redirected to m.mysite.com. Temporary decision was to host images for email at m.mysite.com.

I added another condition to RewriteCond, after `RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !macintosh [NC]`:
`RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^googlebot [NC]`
But this doesn't seem to work. If image is not in m.mysite.com, it is not accessible in Gmail.

**UPD:**

This is the string that solved my problem: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^macintosh|GoogleImageProxy [NC]`

Thanks to Abhishek gurjar for help.

Comment: This `RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^googlebot [NC]` didn't work probably because Google bot's user agent doesn't always starts with "Googlebot", but contains it [ref](https://developers.whatismybrowser.com/useragents/explore/software_name/googlebot/). So you had simply to remove ^ from your RewriteCond this way: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !googlebot [NC]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below conditions in your rule comment out existing similar conditions for testing.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "symbian|midp|wap|phone|pocket|mobile|pda|psp" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^macintosh|Googlebot [NC]
```

Comment: Not working :( Maybe bot that grabs images for email has different name, not Googlebot.

Comment: Check here also for agent name https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1061943?hl=en

Comment: When changed `Googlebot` to `Google`, I got it worked.

Comment: Erm... Does any mobile browser user agent string contain 'Google'? :D

Comment: Eureka! Viewed apache logs and found the wanted bot: `GoogleImageProxy`.